# jest --collect-coverage marks files as 100% covered even there is no test for them

Tags: jestjs, code-coverage, istanbul

I am trying coverage feature on jest tests but output shows 100% coverage for files which are referenced by tests, but not covered at all.. mostly they are just dependencies of modules which are tested and I am far from using all exported methods from them. Any idea why I am getting this phantom coverage? Thanks for any hint

```
--------------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                                  |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
--------------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files                             |     6.93 |     5.48 |     3.22 |     7.18 |                   |
 src                                  |    10.11 |    10.53 |     5.88 |    10.11 |                   |
  const.ts                            |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  utilities.ts                        |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
... etc
```

utilities.ts  have meny exported methods but no one is tested yet and are counted as 100% covered :/

I did not google out any similar case. Most of people ask why their test coverage isnt 100% :D

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of it? I am having the same issue ....

Comment: @Balkyto I think it was fixed once I set 
`
  collectCoverageFrom: ['<rootDir>/src/**/*.(ts|vue)'],
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/src/services/mocks/'],
`
in jest.config.js

Comment: I suppose there are also similar options for CLI ;)

Comment: I tried that, and that "kinda works", but I have a feeling Jest is generous with percentages there. As soon as method is once invoked in test, it seems that it's "100% covered", even if it's doing nothing. But that's the other problem... maybe I'm expecting too much of it.

Comment: I'm having this very same issue: my coverage results is 100%, even for files without tests.  @Luckylooke, would you mind adding your jest.config file to the question?

Comment: Can you solved this issue or any updated ?

Comment: meanwhile I have moved to vue3 + vitest, there is no problem with this, but I can try to post jest.config.js later